# Concat - Undefined Function

Tags: javascript

Using the code below I'm trying to `concat` two objects, but I am getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
function getInvitees(pid, o, u)
{
    var invitees = {};
    var inviteCount = 0;

do {
    var inviteeURL = "https://www.****.com/a/invitees/?pid={0}&offset={1}&user={2}".format(pid, o, u);

    sendRequest(friendsURL, function() { 
        var resp = JSON.parse(e.responseText);
        tmp_invitees = resp['invitees'];
        invitees = invitees.concat(tmp_invitees);
        inviteeCount = tmp_invitees.length;
    });
} while(inviteeCount != 0);

return invitees;
```

}

Why am I unable to contact `invitees` with `tmp_invitees`? I'm able to access `invitees` it just appears `invitees` doesn't have a `concat()` method.

Comment: `invitees` is an object, not an array.

Comment: `invitees` is an object. "concat" is not a method of a standard object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because invitees is a dictionary (or json-object, or JS-Object) and not an array. You can't concat 2 different objects of a different type.

Comment: Oh. I'm confused because `resp['invitees']` contains the JSON object. I thought you could concat a JSON object with another JSON object?

Comment: No only Array objects, not default objects (thus JSON styled objects). You would need to merge those with other means. Try googling for it or search the MDN for dictionary functions)

Comment: I got the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384845/merge-two-json-objects-in-to-one-object ... which is the same as my code above. How are they able to concat 2 objects?

Comment: Because both JSON objects are wrapped inside an Array object `[]`. So what happens there is that the 2 Array's their first key (`0`) get joined and concatted. Thus resulting in a new combined entry. Beware tho. What Quentin answers in that question is not a merge of 2 JSON objects. It's a merge of 2 Array Keys into 1 Array with 2 JSON objects ;) (`[ {} , {} ]`)

Comment: Ah! Got it. I see where I'm going wrong. Going to vote because you helped me understand the problem and solve it.