# how to display multiple json data for a single amchart graph

Tags: java, javascript, json, amcharts

I have a scenario in which I used to display multiple graphs in amcharts for which I had multiple JSONs which were dynamically generated.

Now I need to display all these graphs in a single amchart.

every amchart has multiple graphs individually.

Is there a way in which I could possibly get these individual Jsons to be displayed in a single Amchart?

```
json1 = [{val1,val2....},{val1,val2....}....]
json1 = [{val1,val2....},{val1,val2....}....]
```

These two jsons now are being displayed in 2 different graphs but I need to display in one.

Comment: Do you have a code example of what you've already tried?

Comment: You can [merge two jsons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384845/merge-two-json-javascript-objects-in-to-one-object) into one and then render the chart with the newly created array.

Comment: I cannot do that as the data in both the JSONS are same as in
The x axis is the date and the y axis is the value
if i merge the two jsons the data for the same date will overlap each other.
for eg: json1 [{date:02-03-2015, val1:14}] and json2 [{date:02-03-2015, val1:30}]

In this case only the second value will be displayed in the same graph instead of two different graphs

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/u3ypB/) this is something that i saw but i needed the two graphs instead of the radio to be displayed simultaneously

Comment: Is [this](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/) what you looking for?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for.... i was googling with the wrong keywords :P thanks a lot @anpsmn