# How to merge two json objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Object 1:

```
var string1 = {
    "jobroleid": "1",
    "technologyid": "1",
    "jobrole": "SOFTWARE DEVELOPER",
    "technology": "DOTNET",
    "yoc": [],
    "degree": [],
    "gender": ["Female"],
    "credit": [],
    "minqp": "6",
    "maxqp": "7"
};
```

Object 2:

```
var string2={'name':'hai'};
```

How can I merge the two objects?

Expected output:

```
[{
    "jobroleid": "1",
    "technologyid": "1",
    "jobrole": "SOFTWARE DEVELOPER",
    "technology": "DOTNET",
    "yoc": [],
    "degree": [],
    "gender": ["Female"],
    "credit": [],
    "minqp": "6",
    "maxqp": "7",
    "name": "hai"
}]
```

Comment: Your string1 is not string but an array and string2 is object. Are they actual string you mean ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two json/javascript objects in to one object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384845/merge-two-json-javascript-objects-in-to-one-object)

Comment: You should have a look at [data-types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) in javascript. Your `strings` are `objects` and the expected output is an `array` containing an `object`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the jQuery.[extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method:

```
var combined = []; 
combined.push($.extend({},string1,string2));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x5wjaopm/)

Comment: without using {}, i got a answer <code>$.extend({},string1,string2);</code>

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
string1[0] = $.extend({}, string1[0], string2);
```