# Merging array-valued properties in two objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have following JavaScript objects (new_object and old_object):

new_object:

```
0300 : ["295", "293", "298"],
0800 : ["293", "298"],
0930 : ["295"],
1130 : ["297", "293", "298"],
1230 : ["295"]
```

old_object:

```
0300 : ["297"],
0800 : ["297"],
0930 : ["293"],
```

I want to merge them so that final object would be like

```
0300 : ["295", "293", "298", "297"],
0800 : ["293", "298", "297"],
0930 : ["295", "298", "293"],
1130 : ["297", "293", "298"],
1230 : ["295", "298"]
```

I tried `new_object['0300'].push` with each loop but its not working

How could I merge JavaScript objects ? Are there any best practices?

Comment: Could you include the code you have tried with? Could you explain what exactly is not working, maybe giving us the output you currently get?

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Why would the `0930` key in the result contain `298`? Also, be careful with your keys: if you mean them as strings, fine, but `0300` is an octal constant which means `192`.

Comment: yes the keys are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
for (var key in new_object){
    if(old_object.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        new_object[key] = new_object[key].concat(old_object[key]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Won't this concat `undefined` if the key is missing in `old_object`?

Comment: @torazaburo if there are some missing key in it , insert an if condition before concat to check the validity of old_object[key]

Comment: What if `old_object` has properties that are not in `new_object`?

Comment: @torazaburo object's key are known as properties of object. by checking this condition you are checking if the key of old_object is valid or not

Comment: @torazaburo i updated the answer to consider the case you mentioned that is "if old_object has properties that are not in new_object

Comment: The only problem i am facing is it now have similar items in new object after cancat. is there any way to do it easily and without using loop ?

Comment: instead of new_object[key] = new_object[key].concat(old_object[key]); use: for (var i = 0; i < old_object[key].length; i++) { if (new_object[key].indexOf(old_object[key][i]) > -1) {new_object[key].push(old_object[key][i]); } }

Comment: @Sherif you made a mistake in my answer after edit. the if condition nchecks the validity of old_object[key] and if it's not true means there is not any thing in old_object[key] and it's a mistake to new_object[key] = old_object[key];

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi My apologies. Please feel free to edit it back.

Comment: This accepted answer does not produce the desired results as stated in the question, whether or not that is due to a mistake by the OP in showing his desired results I cannot say. For instance, for 0930, it results in ` ["295", "293"]` instead of `["295", "298", "293"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jquery `$.merge()`

```
var result = $.merge(oldArray, newArray);
```

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384845/merge-two-json-javascript-arrays-in-to-one-array)

Comment: Did you test this? I don't think it will do what you want. Also, in general, unless the OP tagged his question jQuery a non-jQuery answer is preferred.

Comment: yes @torazaburo I have tested this, please check working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vinodhan/hootuoph/

Comment: Your fiddle merges individual property values. The job is to merge **each** pair of properties. See http://jsfiddle.net/hootuoph/1/.

Answer (score 0):

I think `new_object['0300'].push` is a wrong syntax.
Try to `new_object[0300].push`.
It works. But output is something strange.

```
var newObject = {0300 : ["295", "293", "298"],0800 : ["293", "298"],0930 : ["295"],1130 : ["297", "293", "298"],1230 : ["295"]}
var oldObject = {0300 : ["297"],0800 : ["297"],0930 : ["293"]}
newObject[0300].push(oldObject[0300])
//console outputs: ["295", "293", "298", ["297"]]
```

So I use concat method.

```
var newObject = {0300 : ["295", "293", "298"],0800 : ["293", "298"],0930 : ["295"],1130 : ["297", "293", "298"],1230 : ["295"]}
var oldObject = {0300 : ["297"],0800 : ["297"],0930 : ["293"]}

newObject[0300].concat(oldObject[0300])
//console outputs: ["295", "293", "298", "297"]
```

Finally, Merge two Json objects.
Try this.

And see this Questions > [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

```
for (var attrname in obj2) { obj1[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually made a proper solution...

```
var final_object = {};

var new_object_properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new_object);
var old_object_properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(old_object);
var new_object_properties_length = new_object_properties.length;
var old_object_properties_length = old_object_properties.length;
if(new_object_properties_length >  old_object_properties_length)
while(--new_object_properties_length){
     var property_name = new_object_properties[new_object_properties_length];
     if(old_object[property_name])
          final_object[property_name] = new_object[property_name].concat(old_object[property_name];
     else
         final_object[property_name] = new_object_properties[new_object_properties_length];
}
else
    while(--old_object_properties_length){
     var property_name = old_object_properties[old_object_properties_length];
     if(new_object[property_name])
          final_object[property_name] = old_object[property_name].concat(new_object[property_name];
     else
         final_object[property_name] = old_object_properties[old_object_properties_length];
}
```

Comment: This algorithm has the rather unfortunate characteristic that for keys in both old and new objects, it will concatenate once in the first loop, then throw that result away and concatenate again in the second loop.

Comment: Yeah, I am confident that there is a better way, just the one I came up with quickly. EDIT: Oh i see its an easy fix :D

Answer (score 0):

First, write a utility function to merge properties with the same key in two objects, based on a merge strategy passed in as a function.

To merge properties with the same key in two objects, we loop over the second list of keys, and either merge the value into the first object (if it has a property with same key), or simply copy it over (if it doesn't). The way this is written it will mutate (overwrite) `o1`:

```
function merge_keys(o1, o2, merge) {
  var keys2 = Object.keys(o2), key;

  for (var i = 0; i < keys2.length; i++) {
    key = keys2[i];
    o1[key] = o1[key] ? merge(o1[key], o2[key]) : o2[key];
  }
}
```

Define the merging strategy you want to use:

```
function concat(a, b) { return a.concat(b); }
```

Then

```
merge_keys(new_object, old_object, concat);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/hootuoph/2/.

If you are programming in ES6, you can write this more compactly using `for...of`:

```
function merge_keys(o1, o2, merge) {
  for (var k of Object.keys(o2)) {
    o1[k] = o1[k] ? merge(o1[k], o2[k]) : o2[k];
  }
}
```

Or if you prefer using `Array#forEach`:

```
function merge_keys(o1, o2, merge) {
  function maybe_merge(k) { o1[k] = o1[k] ? merge(o1[k], o2[k]) : o2[k]; }

  Object.keys(o2).forEach(maybe_merge);
}
```