# combine two json arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two json arrays like,

```
array1 = [{"quantity":"5","detailed_product_id":"1015","detailed_category_id":"9"}]
```

and

```
array2 = [{"quantity":"2","detailed_product_id":"1003","detailed_category_id":"9"}]
```

I have to combine these two arrays into one array like,

```
resultarray = [{"quantity":"5","detailed_product_id":"1015","detailed_category_id":"9"},{"quantity":"2","detailed_product_id":"1003","detailed_category_id":"9"}]
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two json/javascript arrays in to one array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384845/merge-two-json-javascript-arrays-in-to-one-array)

Comment: How do you tell if you have dup array items? Or do you care?

Answer (score 4):

```js
array1 = [{"quantity":"5","detailed_product_id":"1015","detailed_category_id":"9"}]
array2 = [{"quantity":"2","detailed_product_id":"1003","detailed_category_id":"9"}]
console.log(array1.concat(array2));
```

Comment: It's not working. Getting result like, [{"quantity":"2","detailed_product_id":"1003","detailed_category_id":"9"}][{"quantity":"5","detailed_product_id":"1003","detailed_category_id":"9"}]

Comment: Above returns exactly what you asked for @Arya, log the resulting array instead of the two orriginal ones

Comment: after concatenating two arrays I am getting the above result @baao

Comment: Just click on "run code snippet". The resulting array is exactly as in your question. @Arya

Answer (score 3):

**You can do this using Es 6 new feature:**

```
array1=[{"quantity":"5","detailed_product_id":"1015","detailed_category_id":"9"}]

array2 = [{"quantity":"2","detailed_product_id":"1003","detailed_category_id":"9"}]

var combineJsonArray = [...array1, ...array2 ];

//output should be like this [ {"quantity":"5","detailed_product_id":"1015","detailed_category_id":"9"},
  {"quantity":"2","detailed_product_id":"1003","detailed_category_id":"9"}]
```

**Or You can put extra string or anything between two JSON array:**

```
var array3= [...array1,"test", ...array2];

// output should  be like this :  [ {"quantity":"5","detailed_product_id":"1015","detailed_category_id":"9"},"test",
  {"quantity":"2","detailed_product_id":"1003","detailed_category_id":"9"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function.

```
var resultarray = array1.concat(array2);
```

Result shown below:

```js
array1 = [{
  "quantity": "5",
  "detailed_product_id": "1015",
  "detailed_category_id": "9"
}];

array2 = [{
  "quantity": "2",
  "detailed_product_id": "1003",
  "detailed_category_id": "9"
}];

console.log(array1.concat(array2));
```

Comment: @gedq its exactly asked like the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try [array.concat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) for this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var json1 = [{
            "quantity": "5",
            "detailed_product_id": "1015",
            "detailed_category_id": "9"
        }];
        var json2 = [{
            "quantity": "2",
            "detailed_product_id": "1003",
            "detailed_category_id": "9"
        }]
        var json3 = json2.concat(json1);
        console.log(json3)
    </script>
</head>

</html>
```