# How to merge 2 Objects taken by input's val

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, merge

I have two JSON objects and I want to merge them:

```
Object1: {"9":{"322":{"option0":"177"}}}
Object2: {"10":{"323":{"option":"456"}}}
```

And I want for final result to be like:

```
{
    "9": {
        "322": {
            "option0": "177"
        }
    },
    "10": {
        "323": {
            "option": "456"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the [concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384845/merge-two-json-javascript-arrays-in-to-one-array) method, but the result is this:

```
{
    "9":{
        "322":{
            "option0":"177"
        }
    }
}
{
    "10":{
        "323":{
            "option":"456"
        }
    }
}
```

PS: The objects are taken by input like so:

```
var object1 = $('input').val();
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Side note: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. You've said you've used `concat`, so you're not dealing with a string.

Comment: Could you give a clearer example of the input in the first example. Your description states they are arrays, yet the output would indicate they are objects.

Comment: thanks guys, I've change it.

Comment: And also these are just `objects` there's no such a JSON object.

Comment: @zagzter thanks the clarification re the input boxes. I've updated my answer to work on that basis - take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.assign()`

```js
const Array1 = {"9":{"322":{"option0":"177"}}}
const Array2 = {"10":{"323":{"option":"456"}}}

let newObject = Object.assign({}, Array1, Array2);

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: output of the log is getting like: 0: "{", 1: """, 2: "1", 3: "0", 4: """, 5: ":", 6: "

Comment: @zagzter perhaps you update your question with relevant information?

Comment: @zagzter that did not make it an clearer. Show RELEVANT and POSSIBLE input and expected output

Answer (score 2):

ES6 way:

```
const object1 = {"9":{"322":{"option0":"177"}}}
const object2 = {"10":{"323":{"option":"456"}}}

const object3 = { ...object1, ...object2 }

console.log(object3)
```

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLxBdK?editors=0001

Use ES6 syntax whenever possible.

- shorter code
- more readable usually
- this case in particular allows you to easily do deep merges (which was a pain before)
- faster

Comment: But do not you will have to compile with Babel if you want any IE/Edge support

Comment: Am kinda radical on that. IE is evil. Edge actually supports spread operator:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

I would rather boycott IE since it s so slow on implementing main language of the WWW new features comparing to all other browsers (and always have been so)

Just an opinion in sea of opinions, dont start a war over it please :D

Comment: and of course, you are right about IE - you need Babel in its case

Comment: and I also added **whenever possible** in my post. Sometimes there are some limitations (like IE limitations) <coughing suggestively>

Comment: Meantime in the real world we have to support the default browser

Comment: not sure about your *real* but in everybody elses world IE is used by <drums...> 3% of users :)
http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share

That is **not** default. You work for IE or what?

Comment: browser wars ftw <3

Comment: Among those 3% (IE10 or lower) of our users, there are several that could write emails to the top management and complain...

Comment: I just realise that MSIE in the user agent are IE<11 - so currently one third of accesses are IE11 useragents - and we are mostly accessed by Desktops - where your site quotes 7%IE - [higher in Europe](http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/desktop/europe), even [higher in the US](http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/desktop/north-america)

Comment: sure, altogether I of course know that most of the projects need and DO support IE11. And usually support/dont support is not my decision anyway. Am just theorizing in the end: ) 
ES6 is becoming a standard more and more as well as tons of project use Babel which is not big overhead usually.

Comment: As long as you are not thinking that 3% is the actual % :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually these are `objects` and not JSON `Arrays`, and you got an `array` as result because `Array#concat()` will return an `array` and what you want is an `object`.

So what you can do is to use **[`Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**:

```
let obj = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(o1), JSON.parse(o2));
```

**Note:**

If you take these objects from `input`, you will be getting them as `strings` you need to parse them with `JSON.parse()` to getb the right `objects`.

```js
let o1  = '{"9":{"322":{"option0":"177"}}}';
let o2 =  '{"10":{"323":{"option":"456"}}}';

let obj = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(o1), JSON.parse(o2));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @mplungjan I did, I just wanted to mention that these aren't arrays.

Comment: @zagzter If you are taking them from the input so they will be `strings` you need to parse them first, so they will be `objects`. Check my update.

Comment: @zagzter And to get the result object back as a `string` and use it in an `input` val, you need to use `$("#input").val(JSON.stringify(obj))`..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting the values from a text field, they will initially be JSON strings. In order to treat them like objects and merge then you need to parse them first. Then you can achieve your desired output using jQuery's `$.extend()` method, which merges one object into another.

Demo:

```js
var obj1 = JSON.parse($("#obj1").val());
var obj2 = JSON.parse($("#obj2").val());
var merged= $.extend({}, obj1, obj2);
console.log(merged);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="obj1" value='{"9":{"322":{"option0":"177"}}}'/>
<input type="text" id="obj2" value='{"10":{"323":{"option":"456"}}}'/>
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: thank you ADyson! Can I also insert the merged variable into another input ($('input').val(merged))?

Comment: did it with JSON.stringify